# Jquery file upload error method not allowed

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using jquery file upload plugin and I am not able to upload the file.

I am unable to get the code to run on my application. 
I get error "method not allowed" when I click on start button.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Where are you getting the error from? the js library or your php handler? show us your code also.

Comment: Its error 405...Its happening on my app running locally

Comment: yea 405 is a http error; can't really help you without seeing your code. You must be doing something wrong in your code. Have you checked the error logs on your server? If you haven't turned them on, I suggest you do whilst you are developing to capture background errors to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the server that is suppose to handle the upload is responding with a response code of 503.

This link will give you an idea why it's responding with the specified error code.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html